# Adding dynamically path to .bashrc or .bash_profile using shell command on Mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I am creating a new command to run few codes in python.

In order to install the command I have created install.sh file.

In the shell file I move a shell file, make it executable. But in order to access the command I have to add the path to .bashrc or .bash_profile manually.

I want to add class file in the install.sh file dynamically so that one does not have to add manually the path. It should also remove the class path on uninstallation.

This is my install.sh commands

`mv $HOME/mycmd/bin/my.sh $HOME/mycmd/bin/my`

`chmod +x  $HOME/mycmd/bin/my`

I have tried `sed -i 'class path' ~/.bashrc` but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a command to do this, just an editor, as it's something you only have to do once. Open `~/.bash_profile` and look for a line that looks like

```
PATH=...
```

(`...` represents some arbitrary set of paths; it's not literal.)

If you find it, add your path to the front of the path like so:

```
PATH=~/mycmd/bin:...
```

If you *don't* find it, add the following to the file.

```
PATH=~/mycmd/bin:$PATH
```

In the future, you can add other directories to this line as necessary. Also, you can add more executables to this directory without having to modify `.bash_profile` any further; the purpose of `PATH` is to tell the shell where to find executable files, not to register each executable individually.

Comment: I am trying to add PATH in .bash_profile or .bashrc using shells script or Makefile. I am creating a new command and thats why I want to add bin folder path in .bash_profile from install.sh file or Makefile

Comment: I recommend against that. Your program is always usable by giving the full path; leave it up each user whether they want to modify their PATH.

Comment: The last sentence of this post is misleading. The purpose of the PATH variable is just to specify the directories to be searched to find a command. There's nothing wrong with pointing to folder that contains a single executable or with storing every executable by itself in its own folder, it all depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do what you're looking for

```
echo -en "PATH=\$PATH:/path/to/my/class\nexport PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```